# PowerShell Script works in Windows 10 but not on Windows Embedded Standard

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I have the following script work in windows 10 but not on windows Embdedded Standard:

```
$LogTime = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss"
$Path1= "TEST\TESTLog_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).txt"
$AffPBS= Get-Process "LLCService.exe" | Select-Object ProcessorAffinity
$AffLC= Get-Process "LCService.exe" | Select-Object ProcessorAffinity
$AffinityLLCFinal = "LLC  " + $AffPBS
$AffinityLCFinal = "LC   " + $AffLC
$FinalOutput = $LogTime+"  " +$AffinityLLCFinal +"     " + $AffinityLCFinal 
$FinalOutput | Out-File -Append $Path1
```

I have run the Powershell_ISE as administrator and also set `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`.

The results I'm getting on Windows 10:

```
10-09-2017_03-31-10  LLC  @{ProcessorAffinity=63}     LC   @{ProcessorAffinity=63}
```

THe results I'm getting on Windows 7:

```
10-09-2017_11-23-26  LLC       LC
```

It seems like the `Get-Process`  isn't working on Windows Embedded Standard. Is there any other way of doing this.

Comment: Why did you decide it is not working? What does this give: `Get-Process "LLCService.exe" | Select-Object ProcessorAffinity` ? If that is empty, what does this give: `Get-Process explorer | select processorAffinity` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Win 10 has PS version 5.1.
Win 7 could have 2.0 or 3.0. You can try to upgrade it. If not, in older Versions, you would have to use `Select-object -ExpandProperty "ProcessorAffinity"` instead of simply using `Select-object "ProcessorAffinity"`.

You could also chose to run it from win 10 and specify the Win7 computer using the `-ComputerName` parameter of `Get-Process`. However, you cannot specify credentials if the win 7 requires different creds that what you are logged on with.

In that case you can use `Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Process -ComputerName "Win7Computer" -Credential $PSCredentialObject` but that will give you a slightly different results. I Could not find the "Processor Affinity " Property on it.

Comment: @Robin Sidharth: Thanks mate for replying promptly. But unfortunately this still isn't working. I tried with the `Select-object -ExpandProperty "ProcessorAffinity"`. This again works with windows 10. I just want to mention here the windows version I'm testing on is `Windows Embedded Standartd` which is a variant of Windows 7 I believe.

Comment: Have you tried using the -Computername parameter from Windows 10 or tried to install a newer version of PS on Win7?

Comment: Mate, I have upgraded the PS on the Embedded Server. It's working fine now. Thanks for your help. Accepting your response as an answer